# Invalid if condition

Tags: c#

How to fix it?
Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```cs
var myAirlineNew = Airline.FromXml(fileName);
var planeList = myAirline.GetPlanes().ToList();
foreach (var plane in planeList) 
{
    for (int count = 0;  count < planeList.Count(); count++)
    {
        if (planeList[count].TakeOffWeight == planeList[count+1].TakeOffWeight)
        {
            myAirline.SortByWeight();
        }
        else myAirline.SortByNumber();

        Console.WriteLine($"Plane: {planeList[count].Type},{planeList[count].Number},{planeList[count].Fcs},{planeList[count].TakeOffWeight} kg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `planeList[count]`? Why don't you simply use `plane` and get rid of the inner `for` loop?

Comment: On which line does the exception occur? You can use the debugger to find out. BTW: no need to have both a foreach and a for loop. One is sufficient.

Comment: You have two nested loops looping over the same list. If you have e.g. 10 planes, this will repeat the code 10 x 10 = 100 times! Also, a `List<T>` has a `Count` property. Don't use the LINQ extension method `Count()` here. Also you are sorting `myAirline` repeatedly. Does this make sense? What exactly gets sorted? The planes? The more  I  look at this code, the less sense it makes to me.

Comment: `planeList[count+1]` won't work if you are on the last item, hence, index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the inner `for` loop and use the `plane` iterator variable instead.

```
var myAirlineNew = Airline.FromXml(fileName);

foreach (var plane in myAirline.GetPlanes()) 
{
    if (plane.TakeOffWeight == plane.TakeOffWeight)
        myAirline.SortByWeight();
    else 
        myAirline.SortByNumber();

    Console.WriteLine($"Plane: {plane.Type},{plane.Number},{plane.Fcs},{plane.TakeOffWeight} kg");
}
```

Comment: But you still have to figure out what the user is trying to do with `if (plane.TakeOffWeight == plane.TakeOffWeight)`

Comment: Is it just me being dumb. What is `if (plane.TakeOffWeight == plane.TakeOffWeight)` supposed to do?

Comment: Quite frankly I focused on the other problems of the code fragment and did not check the condition itself. That line does not make too much sense. I assume that there was some copy-paste issue on the OP side.